# Cassandra token unequal

Tags: cassandra, token

I'm using Cassandra 1.2.11

I setup a cluster of 2 nodes using default configurations like below:

> num_tokens: 256
>
> endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
>
> initial_token:

When 2 nodes are working, I check nodetool status and find that:

> Load        Owns HostID Token
>
> 56.55 KB   86.8%    2e620ec5-f0cd-4d48-afb4-5738c32e5476  5590003725053436641
>
> 42.49 KB   13.2%  704ae042-ce56-4136-99e1-42a5cc12eada  8024527685350563454

Why one node owns 86.8% and another owns 13.2%. I expect they are 50-50.
Could you please advise me on this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

A common cause of this problem is if you start Cassandra with num_tokens=1 (or empty, which is the default in 1.2) and then restart it with num_tokens=256.

If you started Cassandra once, even for a very short time, with this config, then Cassandra will have randomly chosen just one token.  Then when restarted with num_tokens=256 it will split the range, but that won't change the distribution.

You can confirm by looking at the logs, or by seeing if the tokens reported by `nodetool ring` are sequential.

Comment: Actually I thought num_tokens=256 is the default configuration. I need to un-comment this line to activate it. I delete all data and boot 2 nodes again, they are now equal. Thank you.